# Выход из системы с сохранением данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Возникла проблема с сохранением данных после завершения работы системы. Взял код, который записывает звук с устройства, и немного его модифицировал для своих нужд. Но столкнулся с проблемой сохранения данных, если экстренно выключается компьютер. Пробовал через функцию sys.exit и через try ... finally. Может, подскажите какой-нибудь вариант или источник, где можно поискать ответ?

```
import pyaudio
import wave
# имя файла для записи
filename = "recorded1.wav"
# установить размер блока в 1024 сэмпла
chunk = 49152
# образец формата
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
# моно, если хотите стере измените на 2
channels = 1
# 44100 сэмплов в секунду
sample_rate = 11025
record_hours = 3600
# initialize PyAudio object
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
# открыть объект потока как ввод и вывод
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=channels,
                rate=sample_rate,
                input=True,
                output=True,
                frames_per_buffer=chunk)
frames = []
print("Recording...")
for i in range(int(66150 / chunk * record_hours)):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    # если вы хотите слышать свой голос во время записи
    # stream.write(data)
    frames.append(data)
print("Finished recording.")
# остановить и закрыть поток
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
# завершить работу объекта pyaudio
p.terminate()
# сохранить аудиофайл
# открываем файл в режиме 'запись байтов'
wf = wave.open(filename, "wb")
# установить каналы
wf.setnchannels(channels)
# установить формат образца
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
# установить частоту дискретизации
wf.setframerate(sample_rate)
# записываем кадры как байты
wf.writeframes(b"".join(frames))
# закрыть файл
wf.close()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: добавить скрипт в планировщик?

Comment: добавлял в планировщик. он запускается в планировщике в определенное время но работает определенное время (6 часов). после чего он сам выключается. если его завершить раньше это времени он не сохраняется. как сделать что бы при выходе из ос или неожиданном прерывании он сохранял записанное?

Answer (score 0):

Если во время работы вашего кода внезапно отключился компьютер, на него падает кирпич, его заливает вулканической лавой, на дом падает метеорит и пр. то ничто в этот момент ваши данные, находящиеся в оперативной памяти, уже не спасет. Что бы сохранить данные их надо ПРЕДВАРИТЕЛЬНО записывать на устройство хранения, которое может защитить от некоторых перечисленных выше событий. (Мне приходилось принимать участие в опроекте, в котором данные копировались на устройства хранения, расположенные в более сотни километров от компьютеров в шахте где-то в Альпах - что-бы их сохранить даже в случае атомного взрыва, во как!). Поэтому надо пересмотреть архитектуру вашего приложения, и не на try... except расчитывать, а просто записывать на внешнее устройство входные (или какие вы хотите сохранить данные) даже раньше, чем начнете обработку их очередной входной порции.